# UIButton & UITextField will block UITableViewCell being swipe to delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, delete-row

There are `UIButton` and `UITextField` in the `UITableViewCell`. The delete button[image] will not come up when I swipe over `UIButton` or `UITextField`. I do search for the answers on SO and google, there is a similar questions [Swipe left gestures over UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016324/swipe-left-gestures-over-uitextfield), but no correct answers.

I got this problem on iOS 8.

**Edit**
    After setting `self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;`, it works perfect for cell with `UITextField`. But when i drag start from the `UIButton`, the delete button shows and the `UIButton` fired, which I do not want the `UIButton` get fired.

Comment: i guess you will have to reload tableview after deleting a row

Comment: @NullData I have update my question. Please make sure you understand what's my problem.

Comment: @NullData nothing special in the code, the cell is created in storyboard, and the cell is editable by return YES in - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

Comment: You mean the right most delete button won't show up? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Make sure you swipe on the button.

Comment: @luyuan, Don't see any issue. Works like charm I am using Storyboard. have you added - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: @Lightygalaxy Yes I implemented it. I have updated my question

Comment: Is `.cancelsTouchesInView` set to `YES` on the gesture recognizer? On a vanilla gesture recognizer, `YES` is the default, but who knows what the `UITableView` sets it to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to prevent the `UIButton` from firing in the first place, but `UITableViewCell` has the property `showingDeleteConfirmation` that can be used to check whether the Delete button is being shown. What I do is check this in the `UIButton` action for `TouchUpInside`, like this

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
        // Handle button press
    }
}
```

(This example is from a `UITableViewCell` subclass, so it uses `self` to access the property.)

This, in addition to the

```
tableView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

that you already have, works to get the swipe properly recognized and the button action not performed.